# Enviar HTTP requests mediante un proxy

Tags: python, scraping

he estado tratando de hacer peticiones a una url mediante requests, pero al rato me tiraba el error 429, too many requests, he estado investigando y para solucionar esto tenia que cambiar de proxy, y eso es lo que he estado probando. Pero me salta este error:

raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://

Este es mi código:

```
import requests


proxies = {
    "https": "104.248.63.15:30588",
    "http": "104.248.63.15:30588"
}

url = "https://httpbin.org/ip"

r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: El proxy 104.248.63.15:30588 no es un proxy HTTP, sino un proxy SOCKS.

Comment: Sabes donde puedo conseguir proxies HTTP?

Comment: Google "Free Proxy Server"

Answer (score 1):

**Código**:

```
import requests

proxies = {
    "https": "http://47.90.132.228:3128",
    "http": "http://47.90.132.228:3128"
}

url = "http://httpbin.org/ip"

try:
    r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
    print(r.json())
except:
    print("Sin respuesta")
```

**Explicación**:

`InvalidURL: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://` ya te indica que la URL del proxy tiene que empezar por `http://` o `https://`.

Para solucionarlo, simplemente añade `http://` antes de la dirección de los proxies.

**Resultado**:

```
{'origin': '81.36.5.69, 47.90.132.228'}
```

Comment: Lo he hecho, pero luego me sale este error:

raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002820098A220>, 'Connection to 104.248.63.15 timed out. (connect timeout=3)'))

Comment: Sabes a que se debe?

Comment: He actualizado el código y me funciona correctamente. Información sobre el error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230850/httpsconnectionpool-max-retries-exceeded

Comment: Ahora me sale este nuevo error:       
raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ip (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000023B7FF4A1F0>, 'Connection to 104.248.63.15 timed out. (connect timeout=3)'))

Comment: Es el mismo error de antes. He mejorado el código para manejar excepciones, ahora te debería funcionar correctamente. Prueba a ejecutarlo varias veces. Si aún así no te funciona, por favor revisa tu red o conéctate con Ethernet para tener una conexion estable.